# Dictate color control by text

Tags: c#, string, text

My code:

```
private Color[] sequence;
private Color [] colors =  new Color[]{Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Yellow};
```

---

I'm trying to make the second line be dictated by a textbox `instructions.text` instead of the above function. The textbox.text will contain "Red, Green, Blue, etc"

So I replaced line 2 with this code:

```
    private Color[] colors = File.ReadAllLines("instructions.txt")
             .Select(name => Color.FromName(name))
             .ToArray();*
```

and added this line on top:

```
    public string setinstructions
    {    get { return instructions.Text; }
         set { instructions.Text = "Red, Green, Blue, Yellow"; }
    }
```

Here's the final code. Can someone help me point out what's wrong with it, and perhaps help me fix it. Any help is appreciated, thank you in advance.

```
    public string setinstructions
    {    get { return instructions.Text; }
         set { instructions.Text = "Red, Green, Blue, Yellow"; }
    }

    private Color[] sequence;
    private Color[] colors = File.ReadAllLines("instructions.txt")
             .Select(name => Color.FromName(name))
             .ToArray();**
```

Comment: You could start by telling *us* what is wrong. It won't compile? Runtime exception? What is the exception? If it ran, what did you expect it to do? What happened instead? What have you tried to solve this already? Please elaborate.

Comment: It won't run, because it says instructions.text doesn't exist in the current context

Comment: Okay, lets walk through it then. Where have you defined `instructions`? It doesn't look to me that you've declared it or given it a value anywhere. Can you elaborate on what exactly you want `setinstructions` to do?

Comment: That must be it, sorry I'm new to programming. I thought get/set would have declared it. How can I do this the right way?

Comment: (I need setinstructions to hold a string "Green, Yellow, Blue, etc" so these values will be read instead of new Color[]{Color.Red, Color.Green, Color.Blue, Color.Yellow};)

Comment: See my answer, let me know if this answers your question or you need additional details.

Comment: For one thing, the property is probably `Text`, rather than `text`. C# is case-sensitive. Also, I thought you said you wanted to read from a textbox, but you're reading lines from a file called instructions.txt?

Comment: itsme86, that it! Thank you. So, if I just want it to read from a text file, where should I put the file? (sorry for the nooby question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want an auto-implemented property. Let me show you how to use it properly.

```
public string setinstructions { get; set; }
```

This is equivalent to the following code:

```
private string _setinstructions;
public string setinstructions
{
   get 
   { 
      return _setinstructions; 
   }
   set 
   {
      _setinstructions = value; 
   }
}
```

So just use that first snippet and at some point before you need to use `setinstructions` , use this line of code:

```
this.setinstructions = "Red, Green, Blue, Yellow";
```

This will set the value of `setinstructions` to `Red, Green, Blue, Yellow`.

Comment: Thank you for the help! Is there any "using" references that I need to include? I seem to be getting an error

Comment: @Ashtopher Not for this, no. I could help if you told me *what* the error is and some details about it.